# how to stick component not relative to its direct parent component in css

Tags: css, position, sticky

I have a situation, where position sticky is not working. what I'm trying to do is make below h1 component stick to the top.

```css
.sticky {
position: sticky;
top: 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sticky Position List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="App">
   
      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>
      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>
      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>
      <div class="necessary-div">
        <div class="other-div"> </div>
        <h1 class="sticky">
          position sticky
        </h1>
      </div>
      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>
      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>

      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>
      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>

      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>
     
      <h2>
        Start editing to see some magic happen!
        <br />
      </h2>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I remove the div with the class name "necessary-div" it works fine. but i need it to work with that div.

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your div with the class "app" should have the styling: position: relative; ☺️

Comment: hello, thank you for your time @simon. i tried that, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the sticky div is sticking to the inside of necessary-div. Make necessary-div sticky and it'll work.

```css
.necessary-div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky {}
```

```html
  <div class="App">
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <div class="necessary-div">
      <div class="other-div"> </div>
      <h1 class="sticky">
        position sticky
      </h1>
    </div>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
    <h2>
      Start editing to see some magic happen!
      <br />
    </h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your time @adam, but i need the h1 tag to be sticky, without making the necessary-div sticky,
sorry for not mentioning that in the question..

Comment: Ah okay. I'll have a look. Does the necessary-div have to be there? are you making the h1 tag sticky in the body or the app div?

Comment: yes, it is necessary.  
I want the h1 tag to be sticky in the app div

Comment: So you want the necessary div to scroll past the top of the page but contain the h1 tag text and the h1 tag stick to the top of the page?

Comment: yes, there other div's as well inside the necessary-div, which i don't want be sticky.